# Ruby convert all values in a hash to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following snippet of code to fetch certain columns from the db:

```
 @data =  Topic.select("id,name").where("id in (?)",@question.question_topic.split(",")).map(&:attributes)
```

In the resulting Array of Hashes which is :

**Current:**

```
@data =    [ { "id" => 2, "name" => "Sports" }]
```

**To be changed to:**

```
@data =    [ { "id" => "2", "name" => "Sports" }]
```

I want to convert "id" to `string` from `fixnum`. Id is integer in the db. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Note: After using `.map(&:attributes)` it is not an active record relation.

Comment: Why exactly do you want it as hash, instead of relation of `ActiveRecord` objects?

Comment: what version rails you use? `pluck` is awesome!

Comment: `"id"=> 2` or `"id": 2` ?

Comment: Shiva, updated. I am on rails 3.2

Comment: @VarunJain ok, but why do you call `map(:&attributes)` on this relation? It seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: I need it for the front end. This data  is used to pre populate for jquery tokeninput. Just re read your comment. I had misread it the first time.

Comment: @VarunJain How do you pre-populate this tokeninput?

Comment: It is an attribute "data-pre" in the input box. http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: just want to chime in here.  I think what you currently have is fine.  If the sole purpose of this is for use in jquery tokeninput, you won't have to change the id to string.  if it doesn't work for integers, there's something wrong with your js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with proper `map` usage:

```
topics = Topic.select("id,name").where("id in (?)",@question.question_topic.split(","))
@data = topics.map do |topic|
  {
    'id' => topic.id.to_s,
    'name' => topic.name
  }
end
```

Comment: topic.id and topic.name won't work. I've submitted an edit. In general I think this is a little restrictive. For example what if tomorrow he wants to use something else from that model? Then he'll have to fix it in two places.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is simply

```
@data.each { |obj| obj["id"] = obj["id"].to_s }
```

There isn't really a simpler way (I think that's straightforward enough anyway).

Going by the title which implies a different question - converting every value in the hash to a string you can do this:

```
@data.each do |obj| 
  obj.map do |k, v|        
      {k => v.to_s} 
  end
end
```

Just leaving that there anyway.

Comment: I knew this way, any other way?

Comment: @VarunJain well which of the two are you looking for? All the values converted to strings or just the id attr?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ruby's #inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) here:

```
@data.map do |datum|
  new_datum = datum.inject({}) do |converted_datum, (key, value)|
    converted_datum[key] = value.to_s

    converted_datum
  end
end
```

This will work to convert all values to strings, regardless of the key.

If you are using Rails it can be even cleaner with [Rails' #each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```
@data.map do |datum|
  datum.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), converted_datum|
    converted_datum[key] = value.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@data.each {|data_item| data_item.transform_values!(&:to_s)}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

This will iterate all the key names in the hash and replace the value with the #to_s version of the datum associated with the key. nil's converted to empty strings. Also, this assumes you don't have complex data within the hash like embedded arrays or other hashes.

```
def hash_values_to_string(hash)
  hash.keys.each {|k| hash[k]=hash[k].to_s}; hash
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.